# What is this form doing that causes an error?

Tags: php, html

Any file linked from the form in the code below causes the page to throw out this error:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /savetodb.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Code:

```
<div id="form">
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM textdb WHERE id=1") 
or die(mysql_error());  
$fields = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
<form action="savetodb.php" method="post">
<p><a href="#">Text from DB One</a><br></p>
<br /><?php echo"<input name=\"one\" type=\"text\" id=\"one\" value=\"" .$fields['one']. "\"/>"; ?>
<br /><br />
<p><a href="#">Text from DB 2</a><br></p><br />
  <?php echo"<input name=\"two\" type=\"text\" id=\"two\" value=\"" .$fields['two']. "\">"; ?>
<br /><br />
<p><a href="#">Text from DB 3</a><br></p><br /><?php echo"<input name=\"three\" type=\"text\" id=\"three\" value=\"" .$fields['three']. "\">"; ?>
<br /><br />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save"></form>
</div>
```

Have I missed something in the code that could be causing this? The files permissions are set to 655 (the default for my server, 777 isn't allowed).

The form imports data from the database in to editable fields, then when you click save, it should save that info back to the database. When you click save, the browser gives you the Forbidden error.

Please don't point out I should be using PDO statement, I'm still learning :/

**The problem is not with the code, but with a server plugin called modsecurity. It has been disabled by my host now and works perfectly! If you are getting similar errors please contact your host, to save you a few days of trouble shooting!**

Comment: It is blank. Nothing in the .htaccess file.

Comment: It is odd that you do not have permissions to access savetodb.php. What are the permissions of the file that contains the form? Can you open savetodb.php directly, bypassing the form(just as a test)?

Comment: Sorry guys, it was a problem with modsecurity. It has been disabled by my host now, and everything works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, it was a problem with modsecurity as there is HTML in the form, it was blocking the file from working.

Very odd problem which my host hast fixed now.

I'll leave this here in case anyone in future is experiencing the same problems. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

There are some possible causes to this:

- the file  /savetodb.php does not exists
- the file permissions do not allow the webserver process to access the file
- you have configured your .htaccess or virtualhost in a way that this file can not be accessed.

Comment: Both files exist and can be seen without submitting the form, by visiting the url in browser. The file permissions are set like every other page on the site (which work flawlessly). I'm not sure if I have access to my .htaccess file. It's just this one file. I find it very odd! :(

Comment: @GT22 Are there other parts of your site that uses POST, and has it working correctly? Also, could you tell us exactly where the form file lives in relation to the saveToDb.php? Are they in the same directory?

Comment: It was a problem with modsecurity apparently. Switched that off and it now works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Error 404 means file not found.

Make sure the path is correct and check for rewrite-rules in .htaccess

Comment: Your .htaccess still seems to require some fixup, since it doesn't find the ErrorDocument 404.

Comment: If you work with something like Joomla for example, make sure that it filters many exploit-typical strings and such. Which would address you, again, to .htaccess

Comment: It was a problem with modsecurity. It has been disabled by my host now and works perfectly!